# Difference between first and last record of the day, grouped by day

Tags: mysql

Here is a table that I have:

```
+----+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| id | time                | gebr_laag_tarief | gebr_hoog_tarief | leve_laag_tarief | leve_hoog_tarief | huidig_verbruik | huidig_levering | gas |
+----+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
|  1 | 2015-12-22 17:46:33 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              20 |               0 |   0 |
|  2 | 2015-12-22 17:46:38 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              30 |               0 |   0 |
|  3 | 2015-12-22 17:46:42 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              40 |               0 |   0 |
|  4 | 2015-12-22 17:46:45 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              50 |               0 |   0 |
|  5 | 2015-12-22 17:46:52 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              60 |               0 |   0 |
|  6 | 2015-12-22 17:46:56 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              70 |               0 |   0 |
|  7 | 2015-12-22 17:47:00 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              80 |               0 |   0 |
|  8 | 2015-12-22 17:47:02 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              90 |               0 |   0 |
|  9 | 2015-12-22 17:47:06 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |             100 |               0 |   0 |
| 10 | 2015-12-22 17:47:11 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              95 |               0 |   0 |
| 11 | 2015-12-22 17:47:19 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              85 |               0 |   0 |
| 12 | 2015-12-22 17:47:22 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              75 |               0 |   0 |
| 13 | 2015-12-24 17:47:24 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              65 |               0 |   0 |
| 14 | 2015-12-25 17:47:27 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              55 |               0 |   0 |
| 15 | 2015-12-26 18:08:50 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |              35 |               0 |   0 |
| 16 | 2015-12-26 21:37:57 |               10 |               20 |                0 |                0 |               0 |               0 |   0 |
| 17 | 2015-12-26 21:38:06 |               20 |               40 |                0 |                0 |               0 |               0 |   0 |
| 18 | 2015-12-26 21:38:14 |               25 |               45 |                0 |                0 |               0 |               0 |   0 |
| 19 | 2015-12-26 21:38:22 |               30 |               50 |                0 |                0 |               0 |               0 |   0 |
| 20 | 2015-12-27 14:47:27 |               31 |               52 |                0 |                0 |              10 |               0 |   0 |
| 21 | 2015-12-27 14:47:40 |               36 |               53 |                0 |                0 |              15 |               0 |   0 |
| 22 | 2015-12-27 14:47:49 |               37 |               53 |                0 |                0 |               5 |               0 |   0 |
| 23 | 2015-12-27 14:48:00 |               37 |               54 |                0 |                0 |               6 |               0 |   0 |
| 24 | 2015-12-27 14:48:15 |               40 |               55 |                0 |                0 |              30 |               0 |   0 |
+----+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
```

Here is what I try to achieve:

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| Day      | diff_gebr_laag_tarief |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 25       |                     0 |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 26       |                    30 |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 27       |                    10 |
+----------+-----------------------+
```

In other words, I want per day-number, in the current month (ie. 26th of the current month) the difference since the last record of the previous day-number. The last record is, in this explanation, defined as the last time a record is added on a specific day but it should also be the greatest id-number of that specific day (ie. 14 | 2015-12-25 17:47:27 or 19 | 2015-12-26 21:38:22)

I want to have the differences for gebr_laag_tarief, gebr_hoog_tarief, leve_laag_tarief, leve_hoog_tarief and gas. 0 (NULL) values can exist but every row should contain either the same or a higher number than the previous one. Also, there will be records added each day and no days are skipped. I just added some random values to get the query going.

I was on this path:

```
SELECT Sub1.JustDate, (b.gebr_laag_tarief - a.gebr_laag_tarief) AS Verschil
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), '%Y-%m-%d') AS JustDate, MIN(time) AS MinTimeStamp, MAX(time) AS MaxTimeStamp
    -> FROM meetwaarden
    -> GROUP BY JustDate) Sub1
    -> INNER JOIN meetwaarden a on Sub1.MinTimeStamp = a.time
    -> INNER JOIN meetwaarden b on Sub1.MaxTimeStamp = b.time
    -> ;
```

But it doesn't do what completely what I had in mind, being the return of the day-number and the difference is the total difference instead of the daily difference.

Hope I am clear enough! Thanks for thinking with me. First post so go easy on me. I have search stackoverflow and the net but just can't find the answer -or- can't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! you did fine with your question... gave us data, an attempt and your desired outcome so good job on that one! I dont completely understand what you mean by the difference... looking at the numbers, the only thing I can see is that the last value on any day is returned. but it is subtracted from the previous day's last value? is that correct?

Comment: I understand your question and what you are trying to achieve. How about creating a stored procedure on the database? And use temporary tables to get step by step where you need to be

Comment: Almost John Ruddell. Probably what you meant was: The last value on any day is returned, but the previous day's last value is subtracted. Otherwise we would get negative numbers.
PierreDuc - I don't quit understand what you mean by 'stored procedure'. I have data inserted in this table every x minutes and use the latest data entered constantly to display up-to-date data on a screen.

Comment: I think this is impossible. MySQL always executes the GROUP BY before the ORDER BY clause, even if you put views in between. Because of that, you can only get the first value of the day out of that table (because the rows were inserted in that order).

Comment: @marstato thats not true. you can self join the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your query you just need to specify on your join condition that the day is the previous day for the second join

```
SELECT t.my_time,DATE(b.my_time), MAX(a.tar) - MAX(b.tar) as diff
FROM 
(   SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(my_time) as my_time
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY DATE(my_time)
) t
LEFT JOIN test a ON a.id = t.max_id 
LEFT JOIN test b ON DATE(b.my_time) + INTERVAL 1 DAY = DATE(a.my_time)
WHERE b.my_time is not null
GROUP BY t.my_time
```

**[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/084df/1)**

translating it over to your table / query

```
SELECT DATE(t.my_time), MAX(a.gebr_laag_tarief) - MAX(b.gebr_laag_tarief) as diff_gebr_laag_tarief
FROM 
(   SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(time) as my_time
    FROM meetwaarden 
    GROUP BY DATE(time)
) t
LEFT JOIN meetwaarden a ON a.id = t.max_id 
LEFT JOIN meetwaarden b ON DATE(b.time) + INTERVAL 1 DAY = DATE(a.time)
WHERE b.time is not null
GROUP BY t.my_time
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3688/1)

outputs:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
| day | diff_gebr_laag_tarief |
+-----+-----------------------+
| 25  | 0                     |
| 26  | 30                    |
| 27  | 10                    |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: That seem to work as well :) but what happens if two months are in the same table? Wouldn't it go wrong on the `DAY(b.time) - 1 = DAY(a.time)`, and the GROUP BY ?

Comment: @PierreDuc yea I already thought of that. you can add month and year if desired.. but I think it may be ok with the sequential id's [**see fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0502b/2)

Comment: @PierreDuc I went ahead though and added month and year.. cuz its most likely a better solution / less error prone

Comment: That seems better indeed. But wouldn't it be more readable and perhaps faster to join on `DATE(b.time) = DATE_ADD(DATE(a.time), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` ?

Comment: @PierreDuc or even better get rid of the DATE_ADD and just do `DATE(b.my_time) + INTERVAL 1 DAY = DATE(a.my_time)`

Comment: Oh dear. I guess there is still room to learn something new every day. You think Arjan_IO still cares about us though? ;)

Comment: @PierreDuc probably not... I think he got his answer and is on his way lol.. new users man :P

Comment: I do care! But I live in Europe and work early shifts so I was already in bed. Now back on it though. For the moment it shouts at me "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'my_time' in 'field list' " so I need to figure out where it goes wrong ;)

Comment: Because of that error I thought I change "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(my_time) as my_time" into "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(time) as my_time" as I think this is where my_time is set and it does know the field time. But that didn't help nor did changing it in 'time'.

Comment: @Arjan_IO haha ok cool, most people that come to the site for the first time dont accept an answer :/ so I think I know what the problem was. I updated my answer with the correct query.. [**I also translated the fiddle over to your schema to make sure the query runs**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3688/1). try that out and let me know if it works! :)

Comment: Thanks John Ruddell! It works very well. I now see I had to change more than one my_time in order to make it work :)
Just a quick one to finish: if I do add as many rows as I said in a comment in the answer provided by PierreDuc (1440 records a day), which query would be quicker to run? Yours or PierreDuc's one? Or do you indeed recommend using a Stored Procedure. I have no clue at all how to set that up en use it in my database in order to speed things up.
I looking for the best answer here and thank you both for the valuable input. Something to be learned everyday!

Comment: @Arjan_IO totally not trying to toot my own horn here, but the answer I provided is going to be a lot faster and more feasible for larger sets of data. if you want to test it out you can... try running both on a smaller set of data like a few hundred rows... and look at the execution time for the queries. fractions of a second end up be minutes / hours with larger sets of data

Comment: @Arjan_IO I wouldn't use a stored procedure, its basically a function that you can call in mysql that you have created. it can do a few additional things, but probably not really needed here. the problem with PierreDuc's answer is that it is not only a correlated subquery, its using aggregate functions and creating a new date DATE_SUB for every row squared. that will eventually be a huge load on the database.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Really helpful! I also need this function to check per month and per year values but that is just changing the interval length of course. Also, only data from this current month should be shown if the output is 'per day', if multiple months exists but that needs to go into the WHERE statement so I am on my way into finishing this project here. Very nice :)
-Happy me-

Comment: @Arjan_IO awesome! if you need any more help on this just let me know and I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? It groups by `DATE` and selects the max `gebr_laag_tarief`. It then substracts the max from the previous day.

```
SELECT
     DATE(m.time) as date,
     MAX(m.gebr_laag_tarief) - (
           SELECT 
              MAX(mm.gebr_laag_tarief) 
           FROM 
              meetwaarden as mm 
           WHERE 
              DATE(mm.time) = DATE_SUB(DATE(m.time), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     ) as gebr_diff
FROM
     meetwaarden as m
GROUP BY
     date
;
```

---

**addendum**

If you are worried about performance as @JohnRuddell, which I can understand. Perhaps you should consider a Stored Procedure. It would be something like this:

Create a temporary table by selecting all `MAX(gebr)` columns and group them by `DATE(m.time)`. Add an index on the date column.

Join this table with itself where the date column differs a day, and subtract the corresponding `gebr` columns.

Comment: this does solve the answer... but at a great cost. you are performing a correlated dependent subquery in the select... meaning for every row you are selecting every row again.. if theres 4 rows thats 16 scans... 500 rows is 250,000 scans... you can do the math.. if this table has millions of rows.. this query could take hours

Comment: @JohnRuddell With proper indexes I'm sure the damage won't be that drastic. The input seems to be changed a couple times a day. When it reaches a million, `mysql` will be outdated :). But i get your point. That's why my initial comment is to create a stored procedure

Comment: I personally had to deal with this exact issue at my work... with the proper indexes queries were taking 20 minutes.. on about 60k rows.

Comment: Mmm, even though I've solved issues like this at my work as well, I was using state of the art equipment and I'm pretty sure I got it below a few seconds. But i will try it at my home pc when i get back from my holiday. I'm actually quite curious how big an impact it really has

Comment: Works like a treat! On one hand I am not that bothered about performance but on the other hand, I do plan to have a new record inserted every minute, that is 1440 records a day and about 525600 a year. Maybe I shall do a 5 minute interval but that means changing my complete setup because I still want some specific values to update very minute. I must admit that I do not have a clue about Stored Procedures and how to apply/use them :(